# SwiftUI: Marking button as default with `View.defaultFocus()` does nothing on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, focus

I have a simple macOS app where I want to tell the Focus subsystem that a specific button should get the focus by default:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @FocusState private var focusedElement: FocusedElement?
    @Namespace private var namespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.makeButton(element: .button1)
            self.makeButton(element: .button2)
                .prefersDefaultFocus(in: self.namespace) // doesn't have any effect
        }
        .defaultFocus(self.$focusedElement, .button2) // doesn't have any effect
        .focusScope(self.namespace)
        .onChange(of: self.focusedElement) { newValue in
            print("focusedElement:", newValue.debugDescription )
        }
    }
}

private extension ContentView {

    enum FocusedElement: Hashable, Identifiable {
        case button2
        case button1

        var id: FocusedElement { self }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func makeButton(element: FocusedElement) -> some View {
        Button(action: { }, label: {
            Text(String(describing: element))
        })
        .id(element)
        .focused(self.$focusedElement, equals: element)
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

After some more experiments, I found a way how to make it work. For some odd reason, `.buttonStyle` view modifier seems to have a great effect on how the `defaultFocus()` (doesn't) work.

I have noticed the following behavior:

**1. No `.buttonStyle` is provided or any button style but `.buttonStyle(.plain)` is provided**

- Wrong button is focused (it's the first one in the list)

```
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.makeButton(element: .button1)
            self.makeButton(element: .button2)
                .prefersDefaultFocus(in: self.namespace) // doesn't have any effect
        }
        .buttonStyle(.automatic) // `defaultFocus` doesn't work with anything but `.plain` or a custom buttons style
        .defaultFocus(self.$focusedElement, .button2) // doesn't have any effect
        .focusScope(self.namespace)
        .onChange(of: self.focusedElement) { newValue in
            print("focusedElement:", newValue.debugDescription )
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of 2 buttons with the wrong one focused]

**2. A Custom `ButtonStyle` or `.buttonStyle(.plain) is provided`**

- `.defaultFocus()` view modifier seems to work as expected

[image: Screenshot of 2 buttons with the correct one focused]

Whole code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    // Focus management
    @FocusState private var focusedElement: FocusedElement?
    @Namespace private var namespace

    // MARK: - View

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.makeButton(element: .button1)
            self.makeButton(element: .button2)
                .prefersDefaultFocus(in: self.namespace) // Doesn't have any effect even with `buttonStyle(.plain)`
        }
        .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle()) // Using `.plain` or `MyButtonStyle()` makes the .defaultFocus work as expected
        .defaultFocus(self.$focusedElement, .button2) // Does seem to work when `buttonStyle(.plain)` or `.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())` is specified
        .focusScope(self.namespace)
        .onChange(of: self.focusedElement) { newValue in
            print("focusedElement:", newValue.debugDescription )
        }
    }
}

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(5.0)
            .background(.quaternary, in: Capsule())
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}
```

**3. A Custom `PrimitiveButtonStyle` is provided`**

- No button is focused or focusable by default. You need to explicitly add `.focusable()` view modifier:

```
struct MyButtonStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(5.0)
            .background(.quaternary, in: Capsule())
            .focusable() // PrimitiveButtonStyle doesn't make focusable buttons by default
    }
}
```